# How To Track For Which Foreign Key To Add A Value To? (ex: Add The Data For The Correct User FK)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have no idea how to even phrase this correctly, so I hope my title was not too far off.

I know how to add values to a table using PHP and passing values via SQL. However, what I don't know how to do is how to ensure the correct foreign key is used for the particular entry.

I think it's best to describe through example.

Say I have a userbase table that has a usernameID(PK). Now say I have another table called age and that has a column called age and usernameID(FK).

So what I'm saying is that there is a usernameID as a foreign key in the age table. Now, say when I have a form on a website and it asks for an age for a person and that person is logged in, how can I ensure that when I add the age of this particular user, that it gets added for the correct usernameID(FK). I'm going to make the assumption that the usernameID is all ready created, but I juts need to know how to ensure that the data gets connected to the right FK.

Does this make sense what I am saying? I've been searching google for this but have no idea how to describe what I even want!

Answer (score 1):

While creating table define foreign key constraint.
Eg.

```
CREATE TABLE Age
(
id int NOT NULL,
age int NOT NULL,
username varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES User(username)
);
```

Here, User is the parent table where username column as primary key and in age table as foreign key. If you have used this in your DB for defining FK then on your PHP code it auto show err if trying to put anything other than value allowed.

I hope it will help.

Comment: how can you know what the foreign key is for this person?

Comment: and I have something I created in database that will auto generate the primary key I believe

Comment: I all ready have the table created, I am adding values to the table. So I am attempting to add values to the table and there is a FK there that is needed, I'm trying to dynamically figure out which UserPK is needed to add to the database

Comment: if you define this 'FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES User(username)' constraint then it will auto detected by DB.

Comment: it is not a question of how the DB structure is setup. i all reayd have the DB working fine and I can add values fine. I'm just saying, for a particular table, I have 2 columsn I need to fill that include a foreign key and an age. Say I want to add an age for someone, so the "age" column gets filled to 18, but the FK for the userID, how to know which usernamePK is added?

Comment: how to know which usernamePK is added ? 
when u run insert query for this then after successful insert, can fetch last insert id that can be used as foreign key for another table.

or you can go for trigger concept
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/